# jQuery file upload error

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I've used quite a few examples in trying to create a script to upload a file  but I'm having a host of problems trying.

The second line trying to get the file data is giving me the following error:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined"

If do just "var file = $("#fileInput"+ID)" I get the file users local file location.

Any thoughts on the error?

```js
function uploadImage(ID){
     var file = $("#fileInput"+ID)[0].files[0];
     var form_data = new FormData();
     form_data.append("file", file);               
     form_data.append("user_id", 123);
  
  $.ajax({
   url: "php/imageUpload.php",
   type: "POST",             
   file: form_data, 
   contentType: false,       
   cache: false,             
   processData:false,        
   success: function(data)   
   {
    alert("sucess");//success
   }
  });    
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do multiple uploads?

Comment: No, one single file

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

Comment: So this worked in the fact that I no longer get an error but seems like its still undefined.
My PHP is throwing and error "Notice: Undefined index"

Comment: this error means there is problem in your php code. if my code helps then please upvote it :)